# Core 2 Quad VS Xeon in PC CPU support

Tags: cpu, xeon, intel-core2

I wonder if an Intel Xeon CPU corresponding to a Core 2 Quad one will work on system which supports Core 2 Quad Processors?

I want to buy a Core 2 Quad but I see many same type Xeon CPUs are on sale.

For Example this HP desktop PC, link below - This says it supports Core 2 Quad but no Xeon support is mentioned.

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01399523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Figured it out and i did that mod which worked. HAPPY
771 Xeon CPUs work only on some motherboards/chipsets
First you just need to verify it it works on your system
Then you must! update BIOS microcode files to add support for Xeon CPUs
That's it... I confirm this mod works on my motherboard ! > IPIBL-LB

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to run 771 Xeons in 775 boards. It is not recommended as it is not the intended design. Instructions can be found here: http://www.delidded.com/lga-771-to-775-adapter/

Answer (score 1):

The [Intel Xeon E5450](http://ark.intel.com/products/33083/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5450-12M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) is an Intel LGA 771 socket CPU.

[image]

The [Core 2 Quad Q9650](http://ark.intel.com/products/35428/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9650-12M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) is an Intel LGA 775 socket CPU.

[image]

The LGA 771 Xeon CPU you are interested in cannot be used on a LGA 775 motherboard.  If you attempted to install a LGA 771 product into a LGA 775 motherboard you would damage both the motherboard and the CPU in the process.

> For example the [HP Compaq dx2400 Business Desktop PC](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01399523) says it supports
>   Core 2 Quad but no Xeon support is mentioned.

**This is because the dx2400 officially only supports LGA 775 CPUs.**  HP isn't going to list LGA 771 CPUs that require a hardware modification in order to support.  There is no way to gurantee or predict if a motherboard will or will not accept the CPU after the LGA 771 to LGA 775 modification.  **The adaptor LGA 771 to LGA 775 modification is a "do at your own risk" type modification.**